# Programa se atasca en un scanf

Tags: c, struct

El programa parece atascado depúes del scanf, aunque me asegure de agregar * y # para que salgan de los while:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STR 150
#define MAX_STUDENT 100

typedef char String[MAX_STR];

typedef struct {
    float execution;
    float code_quality;
    float interview;
} Project;

typedef struct {
    String first_name;
    String last_name;
    Project part[3];
} Student;

Student loadInfo (String info) {
    int contador, i=0, j=0;
    Student datos;
    while(info[i] != '*'){
        datos.first_name[i] = info[i];
        i++;
    }
    if (info[i] == '*'){
        datos.first_name[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s", datos.first_name);
    while (info[i] != '#'){
        
    }
}

int main(){
    String info;
    scanf("%s", info);
    loadInfo(info);
    return 0;
}
```

No sé porque no responde ni se acaba el programa si el uso de las 2 condiciones para salir del while son echas.

Es un programa que te dan información en un string separadas por caracteres. El template que nos dan es este:

<first_name>*<last_name>#<P1.1 Execution>|<P1.1 Code Quality>|<P1.1 Interview>#<P1.2 Execution>|<P1.2 Code Quality>|<P1.2 Interview>#<P1.3 Execution>|<P1.3 Code Quality>|<P1.3 Interview>#

Comment: C no maneja un tipo de dato tipo string, este maneja un arreglo de caracteres, puedes declarar la variable info como `char *info` y en el scanf accedes a la direccion de memoria agregando el `&` antes de la variable, de esta forma `scanf("%s", &info);`.

Comment: no puedo cambiar el tipo de variable, porque así es como me han pedido hacerlo. Todas las lineas por en cima de Student loadInfo (String info){ es algo que no me dejan cambiar, y como esa funcion me pide que info sea una variable String, no puedo cambiarlo a char

Comment: Ya vi el tipedef string, pero lo que falla es el segundo while de la función `loadInfo`, ya sea que le pongas la lógica o lo comentes, ya que se queda siempre en el primer caracter después del `*`.

Comment: pero, puse el printf antes de ese while, y deberia imprimir todo lo que va antes de * antes de que se atasque en el segundo while, pero no lo imprime

Comment: sirivio cuando termine el segundo while, pero sigo sin saber porque no lo imprimió antes

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el segundo while, en el if tu incrementas el i a 1 `i++`, esto es el segundo carácter después del asterisco, por lo que tomando el ejemplo de lo que quieres leer seria el siguiente.

```
<first_name>*<last_name># en este caso el carácter de signo de menor (<) es el que sigue después del *
```

ya cuando entraba en el segundo while, al no tener otra vez el incremente de i, este se vuelve un bucle infinito con el ultimo carácter leído que en este caso es el signo de menor.

por lo que la solución es volver a incrementar el i en el segundo while o quitarlo eso dependerá si se usara o no el while.

```
while(info[i] != '#'){
   i++;
}
```

Eso seria la explicación de porque tu código no finaliza, ya que este sigue en el bucle del while.